# Twitter summary card with large image not giving me the desired results

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I am trying to get the summary with large image preview of the Twitter card on my website.

[Website-link](https://speedo-chi.vercel.app/)

But all I am getting is a small preview with no image

[tweet-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JtkZ.png)

This is the code section:

```
<!-- twitter-card -->
     <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
     <meta name="twitter:site" content="@SPEEDO">
     <meta name="twitter:title" content="SPEEDO">
     <meta name="twitter:description" content="SPEEDO is a web application that, in certain                instances, analyses your internet connection's speed.">
     <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ParamPragyan/SPEEDO/main/card.png">
```

I have tried resizing the image and altering the meta tags multiple times with no results.